# Complete the square to solve for velocity?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I'm going to ask my question, explain my problem, show my work, and then re-state my question.

**Question:** how is my solution for velocity different than another solution that I have found in literature?

**Explanation of my problem:** I have a (hyperbolic? or is it quadratic?) equation relating pressure drop and velocity, $v$:
$$\tag{1} -(dp/dx-\rho g)=\frac{\mu}{kk_{rf}}v+\beta\rho v^2$$
I want to solve this equation for the velocity variable $v$.

**My solution:** I have performed the "complete the square" method, e.g., rearranging Eqn (1)
$$\tag{2} \beta\rho v^2+\frac{\mu}{kk_{rf}}v=-(dp/dx-\rho g)$$
dividing through by $\beta\rho$
$$\tag{3} v^2+\frac{1}{\beta\rho}\frac{\mu}{kk_{rf}}v=\frac{-(dp/dx-\rho g)}{\beta\rho}$$
completing the square by adding $\left(\frac{\mu}{2\beta\rho kk_{rf}}\right)^2$ to both sides:
$$\tag{4} v^2+\frac{\mu}{\beta\rho kk_{rf}}v+\left(\frac{\mu}{2\beta\rho kk_{rf}}\right)^2=\frac{-(dp/dx-\rho g)}{\beta\rho}+\left(\frac{\mu}{2\beta\rho kk_{rf}}\right)^2$$
simplifying the LHS:
$$\tag{5} \left(v+\frac{\mu}{2\beta\rho kk_{rf}}\right)^2=\frac{-(dp/dx-\rho g)}{\beta\rho}+\left(\frac{\mu}{2\beta\rho kk_{rf}}\right)^2$$
taking the squareroot of both sides:
$$\tag{6} v+\frac{\mu}{2\beta\rho kk_{rf}}=\pm \sqrt{\frac{-(dp/dx-\rho g)}{\beta\rho}+\left(\frac{\mu}{2\beta\rho kk_{rf}}\right)^2}$$
and solving for $v$:
$$\tag{7} v=-\frac{\mu}{2\beta\rho kk_{rf}}\pm \sqrt{\frac{-(dp/dx-\rho g)}{\beta\rho}+\left(\frac{\mu}{2\beta\rho kk_{rf}}\right)^2}$$
For the equation to make sense I would take the positive root:
$$\tag{8} v=-\frac{\mu}{2\beta\rho kk_{rf}}+\sqrt{\frac{-(dp/dx-\rho g)}{\beta\rho}+\left(\frac{\mu}{2\beta\rho kk_{rf}}\right)^2}$$

**Back to the question:**  The other solution I have found in literature is this:
$$\tag{9} v=\frac{1}{2k\rho\beta}\left[-\frac{\mu}{k_{rf}}+\sqrt{\left(\frac{\mu}{k_{rf}}\right)^2-4k^2\rho\beta\left(dp/dx+\rho g\right)}\right]$$
Are Equations 8 and 9 equivalent?  If so, how? (Also, is Eqn 1 a hyperbolic or quadratic equation?)

Comment: I found my solution, but I will leave this question up so that someone may answer if they wish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$v=\frac{1}{2k\rho\beta}\left[-\frac{\mu}{k_{rf}}+\sqrt{\left(\frac{\mu}{k_{rf}}\right)^2-4k^2\rho\beta\left(dp/dx+\rho g\right)}\right]$$

$$v=-\frac{\mu}{2\beta\rho kk_{rf}}+\frac{1}{2k\rho\beta}\sqrt{\left(\frac{\mu}{k_{rf}}\right)^2-4k^2\rho\beta\left(dp/dx+\rho g\right)}$$

$$v=-\frac{\mu}{2\beta\rho kk_{rf}}+\sqrt{\frac{1}{4k^2\rho^2\beta^2}\Bigg(\left(\frac{\mu}{k_{rf}}\right)^2-4k^2\rho\beta\left(dp/dx+\rho g\right)\Bigg)}$$

Distribute within the radical to acquire

$$v=-\frac{\mu}{2\beta\rho kk_{rf}}+\sqrt{\left(\frac{\mu}{2\beta\rho kk_{rf}}\right)^2-\frac{(dp/dx-\rho g)}{\beta\rho}}$$

Rearrange to get

$$v=-\frac{\mu}{2\beta\rho kk_{rf}}+\sqrt{\frac{-(dp/dx-\rho g)}{\beta\rho}+\left(\frac{\mu}{2\beta\rho kk_{rf}}\right)^2}$$ as needed.